# Insufficient permissions to access resource in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

Insufficient permissions to access resource

Trying to integrate access control list in my project, here assigned the userid(12345) to guest role.  while i access the url the i am getting the following error

HttpError: Insufficient permissions to access resource
            at /home/smi-user/chrysmo/node_modules/acl/lib/acl.js:649:14
            at tryCatcher (/home/smi-user/chrysmo/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
            at Promise.successAdapter [as _fulfillmentHandler0] (/home/smi-user/chrysmo/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/nodeify.js:23:30)
            at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/home/smi-user/chrysmo/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:579:21)
            at Promise._settlePromises (/home/smi-user/chrysmo/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:697:14)
            at Async._drainQueue (/home/smi-user/chrysmo/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:123:16)
            at Async._drainQueues (/home/smi-user/chrysmo/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:133:10)
            at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/smi-user/chrysmo/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:15:14)
            at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)

**server.js**

```
   var express = require( 'express' );
   var acl = require( 'acl' );
   var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
   var app = express();
   app.use(bodyParser.json());
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
   // Or Using the memory backend
    acl = new acl(new acl.memoryBackend());

   acl.allow([
    {
    roles:['guest','member'],
    allows:[
        {resources:'blogs', permissions:'get'},
        {resources:['forums','news'], permissions:['get','put','delete']}
    ]
    },
    {
    roles:['gold','silver'],
    allows:[
        {resources:'cash', permissions:['sell','exchange']},
        {resources:['account','deposit'], permissions:['put','delete']}
    ]
    }
]);

acl.addUserRoles('12345', 'guest');

app.get( '/blogs/:id',acl.middleware(1,getuserid()),
    function( request, response, next ) {
     console.log("test");
    next();
    }
);

function getuserid(){
    return '12345';
}

// Starting the server
app.listen( 3030, function() {
    console.log( 'ACL example listening on port 3030' );
});
```

Comment: fixed, in acl.resources need to add resources:'/blogs' instead of resources:'blogs'

Comment: already i wrote as in above comment then also i got the same. Should i change anything